Why did the author use "travel by taxi" and "bicycle use" to refer to the distances traveled by these modes of transportation?
In an IELTS sample essay on: Average distances in miles travelled by different modes of travel, a famous IELTS examiner wrote:


Travel by taxi saw the most significant change, with more than a threefold increase from 13 miles per person per year in 1985 to 42 miles in 2000.
Bicycle use fell from 51 to 41 miles over the period shown...


As far as I know, travel and use both refer to actions, not distances, so I would use usage instead because according to OD:

usage means how much something is used

I'm really confused since this examiner used usage in other essays of his, for example, "Internet usage". Why did he switch to "use" and "travel" in this essay? Why are these two words even correct in the first place?

"by" is not really the best preposition to have used there. A mode of travel isn't  itself capable  of traveling. It is an abstraction.  Presumably the traveler is present virtually. This sort of terse chart-ese leads to infelicities.

"use"  can have the same meaning as "usage".  This graph shows electricity use at different times of day.

You can reorder to improve:  This chart shows, by mode of travel, average distance per trip.  "by mode of travel" is adverbial in nature, and describes how the chart is presenting/organizing the data.

I can't see why "Travel by taxi" isn't made parallel to "Travel by bicycle." Note, though, that arguing with standardized tests is a slide into madness, i.e., a frustrating losing battle.

@TimR Thanks for your suggestions. What about the noun phrases? Is "travel by car" = "car use" = "car usage" in this case?

@YosefBaskin Those two sentences are not placed next to each other in the examiner's essay.

@TimR By the way, does "miles traveled using cars" work?

When it says "per person per year" are we to understand that the study  tracked identifiable individuals? Or is each trip on a particular mode of transport considered usage by a new person (even if there is repeat use by the same person)?  In other words, do they mean "trip" when they say "person"?

@TimR: And this chart shows that we're far more likely to use use than usage when graphing "how much electricity is used".

@TimR They calculated the total number of miles English people traveled using taxi, and then divided the result by England's population to have the average number of miles per person.

@FumbleFingers so what can we conclude from that?

You can conclude that TimR is right to say "use" can have the same meaning as "usage". AND that although it's perfectly true that usage can mean how much something is used, it's also true that we use use far more often than usage for that sense. Offhand I can't think of any context where you can't just stick with use, so my advice is to pretend you've never heard of the word usage. There's certainly no point in asking why your IELTS  example uses use. It's the natural / most common choice.

Thank you! What about "travel by taxi"? Nobody has made any comments on how it's equal to "taxi use".
